# How do I get html tags in variables to work?

Tags: html, python-2.7, variables, tags, markdown

My code looks like this

Python:

```
render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")
.
.
.
fileout_text = codecs.open(filename_text, 'r', 'utf-8').read()
text = markdown.markdown(fileout_text)
return render.text_temple(text=text)
```

`text_template.html`:

```
$def with text
     < text>$text < /text>
```

Now `$text` should contain html tags instead of markdown syntax.

My problem is that the tags stay as text when the website is displayed – why is that?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please explain the issue and read how to properly format your code.

Comment: I am sorry. My issue is the the html-tags inside the variable $text dont change the appearance of the text. They stay exactly the same.

Comment: Variables aren't a part of HTML. What language are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template system is escaping the HTML as a security measure. You need to tell the template that the HTML output by Markdown is "safe". Based on your code, I'm assuming you are using web.py. The web.py [docs](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/templetor#filtering) state:

> By default, Templetor uses web.websafe filter to do HTML-encoding.
>
> ```
> >>> render.hello("1 < 2")
> "Hello 1 &lt; 2"
> ```
>
> To turnoff filter use : after $. For example:
>
> ```
> The following will not be html escaped.
> $:form.render()
> ```

So in your template try this:

```
$def with text
     < text>$:text < /text>
```

Adding the colon (`$:text`) will tell the template system to not escape the HTML.

If I guessed incorrectly and you are not using web.py, then tell us which templating system you are using and perhaps we can point you to the right solution. Although, now that you know what the problem is, you could just search the docs for that templating system and find the answer yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Print out your variable, to see that you're not encoding your html tags.

Probably that "`<`" is encoded for `&lt;` and "`>`" is encoded for `&gt;`, that's why it's showing HTML code in your browser.

Comment: The result is <b> exampletext</b> insteed of **exampletext** if I print $text. @MilosOzegovic

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.