# Why are the html tags displayed as text?

Tags: html, python-2.7, tags, markdown

My code looks like this

python:

```
render = web.template.render('templates/', base="layout")
.
.
.
fileout_text = codecs.open(filename_text, 'r', 'utf-8').read()
text = markdown.markdown(fileout_text)
return render.text_temple(text=text)
```

text_template.html:

```
$def with text
     < text>$text < /text>
```

Now $text should contain html tags insted of markdown syntax.
My problem is, that the tags stay as text when the website is displayed.
Any help would be appreciated. I am sorry for my spelling english is not my first language.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/35045361/866026